# Is there a way to promote articles between environments?

Tags: joomla-3.x

Is there an easy way to move articles between Joomla installations? For example in a development/staging/production environment, I have the same 20 articles in each.

If I make a change to all 20 articles in development, does Joomla have a way of promoting those changes to staging, without physically copying those articles by hand?

Also, if I add or remove an article in one, does Joomla have a way to add or remove it in the next environment?

Comment: The way is create a script that do it for you.

Comment: do you mean that goes through the two Joomla database, and compares the content tables? How would do you know which articles needed to be copied over?

Comment: or I guess you could tell the script, since we should know which articles were edited...

Comment: I recommend to manage the articles in one place only. It will be hard to sync if there are changes in several places, but it is not impossible, just hard. I'm going create a answer tell how I would do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look for extensions on the JED. Both [J2XML](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/data-import-a-export/12816) and [SP Transfer](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/data-import-a-export/19274) claim to have this functionaity.

Comment: After looking into these, it looks like SP Transfer may be what I need. It looks like i'll be able to move individual rows in a table using that. Thanks.

Comment: Know that you can do that with J2XML as well, I've done it. Think that was in J2.5 but not sure, seems not to be available in J3 yet.
No experience with SP Transfer yet, but it looks like it extends from content to structure. That would allow for the OTAP workflow.

Comment: Sorry, DTAP meant. OTAP is dutch equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend to manage the articles in one place only. It will be hard to sync if there are changes in several places, but it is not impossible, just hard.

If you manage in one place only, just drop the table data in the other places and insert again with the updated data.

If you want to manage the articles in several places you can compare the modified_date and copy the data of the last modified article to the other places. If articles were inserted in one place only, just insert this article to the other places. If articles were inserted in several places, copy the data of all these articles, drop them from database, and insert again in all database to keep the same id in all databases. This is just a idea about what you will need to do. So, I recommend to manage the articles in one place only.

The more important here is to keep the same Id to the articles between databases.

Answer (score 4):

I have worked with SP Transfer by cyend and it is doing the job pretty well.

But depending on the conditions, I also do this by using a desktop database management app that allows me to perform efficiently database operations.

In my mac I use Sequel Pro.

I can connect remotely via SSH to more than 1 DB server and have opened windows for the databases I am working on at the same time. I can easily choose any records from any table I want, and import/update records to the other table.

There are many cases that I consider this method to be much more efficient and faster for me. 
In the case of copying articles, we assume that the overall db structure and categories organization is the same between the 2 tables, otherwise there is going to create a mess with the assets and the categorization of the articles.

But someone needs to be careful and know what he is doing, because we are dealing directly with the databases.